# Coriolis effect

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, projectile, coriolis-effect

How would I to be able to calculate the Coriolis drift for a ballistic target?
(let's say a bullet shot south from the northen hemisphere, after calculating the acceleration based on latitude  how would I calculate the drift over a period of time? And does the mass of the bullet come into play?)

Comment: This might do it , but I can't say I have used it myself.  http://www.shodor.org/os411/courses/_master/tools/calculators/coriolis/   otherwise I expect most of the equations are on the  appropriate Wikipedia page

Comment: Conceptually, you just figure out how much the target has moved because of the earth's rotation during the flight time of the shell. This is kinematics, caused by working in a rotating reference frame (fixed to the earth), not mechanics, so the mass of the bullet is irrelevant.